# kotlin and kotlinc report different versions

Tags: kotlin, homebrew

I upgraded kotlin compiler using brew in mac os using following command:

`brew upgrade kotlin-compiler`

kotlinc -version prints:

```
kotlinc-jvm 1.2.51 (JRE 1.8.0_171-b11)
```

kotlin -version prints:

```
Kotlin version 1.2.41-release-74 (JRE 1.8.0_171-b11)
```

After upgrade, shouldn't both version be same?

Comment: Have you tried to run `brew upgrade kotlin`?

Comment: brew upgrade  kotlin gives following error: kotlin 1.2.51 already installed

Comment: Maybe you have a second Kotlin installation in you path. `/usr/local/bin/kotlin -version` should print the version of the Kotlin installation from brew

Comment: This morning, MAC OS was upgraded to version 10.13.6. Now correct version is reported. I think the other version got removed during the upgrade. - Thanks